# Is it possible to reference the Name property of a solution through code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Is it possible to reference the name of your solution in code?

I want to pull it to be used as a string similar to how you would use `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name` to pull the name of the current method.

I browsed through the `System.Reflection` class but have not come across anything useful yet.

Comment: Once your project is compiled I don't think there is any solution, nor project, information anymore. Logically they would just exist in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim solutionName As String = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)`

Above will give you you `dll` name which usually is the same as project name.
Make sure below Assembly Name matches your solution name and you will be gold.

[image]

Comment: I am able to load the project name and dynamically create an object based off of it.

Comment: Similar to what you suggest, but this requires me to have more projects than I want.
What I want to do is have one main form that is the startup project among a set of solutions. Then I would like to dynamically create my mainLogic object on the fly based off of the name of the solution. This object would be the unique code in each solution, so each solution would function differently, but maintain a consistent look and feel, and also make updating much easier down the road.
Unfortunately, the more I look into this the more I think it may not be possible.